# How to change the default code generated by SWIG for the allocation of memory for a C structure?

Tags: swig

I am using a flexible array in the structure. So I want to change the memory allocated for that structure with some of my own code. Basically I want to change the new_structname() and structname_variable_set() functions.

```
typedef struct vector{ 
    int x; 
    char y; 
    int arr[0]; 
} vector;
```

here, SWIG generated `new_vector()` function to allocate memory by calling `calloc(1,sizeof(struct vector))` where swig will not handle these type of structure in a special manner. So we need to modify the swig generated new_vector() in order to allocate memory for the flexible array. So is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you need to change them? Switching to an alternative named function with equivalent semantics is fairly easy, but if you want to do more complex stuff you'll need to make deeper changes.

Comment: In the new_structname() function memory is allocated as bellow.
var = calloc(1,sizeof(struct name)). this will consider the size of struct leaving the flexible array. So what I want to do is var = calloc(1,sizeof(struct name)+ size_of_flexi_arr); where size_of_flexi_arr will be given by user.

Comment: I don't want to change the name of the function, I want to change the code inside the function.

Comment: Ok, so how does the user give `size_of_flexi_arr`?

Comment: I am passing the size_of_flexi_arr value from python script.

Comment: How/where? Show an example of what you've got and what you want the wrapped interface to look like.

Comment: typedef struct vector{
             int x;
             char y;
             int arr[0];
}vector;

here, SWIG generated new_vector() function allocate memory by calloc(1,sizeof(struct vector)) where swig will not handle these type of structure in a special manner. So we need to modify the swig generated new_vector() in order to allocate memory for the flexible array. So is there any way to handle this.

Comment: I edited that info into your question (but you can and should do that normally). I'm also assuming you want to explicitly pass the `size_of_flexi_arr` as an argument into the constructor of your vector

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. What you're looking for though is `%extend`. That lets us define new constructors and implement them as we see fit. (It even works with a C compiler, they're only constructors from the perspective of the target language).

Using your `vector` as a starting point we can illustrate this:

```
%module test

%include <stdint.i>

%inline %{
typedef struct vector{ int x; char y; int arr[0]; }vector; 
%}

%extend vector {
    vector(const size_t len) {
        vector *v = calloc(1, sizeof *v + len);
        v->x = len;
        return v;
    }
}
```

With this SWIG synthesises a `new_vector` function in the generated module code as you'd hoped.

I also assumed that you want to record the length inside the struct as one of its members. If that's not the case you can simply delete the assignment I made.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot.